# How is the block layout "vertically biased", and how is inline-block "horizontally biased"?

Tags: css, layout, position, flexbox

> The flexbox layout algorithm is direction-agnostic **as opposed to the block layout, which is vertically-biased, or the inline layout, which is horizontally-biased.**
>   ~ [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FTutorials%2FUsing_CSS_flexible_boxes)

Could somebody care to explain what does that exactly mean?
What are the handicaps of these layouts as opposed to flexbox in terms of **"axis bias"**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have divs in your code (wihout any css styling, divs are "display: block;" by default):

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
```

The divs will be shown on the page like this, vertically:

1

2

3

---

If you have 3 inline tags in your code ("b" tag is "display: inline;" by default):

```
<b>1</b>
<b>2</b>
<b>3</b>
```

They will be shown on the page like this, horizontally:

123

---

Flexbox is opposite to them, flexbox has block, inline, table and some another capabilities. Because flexbox is not block or inline element, flexbox is  "direction"-element.

For example, try to compare PIXEL and VECTOR. (May be it is not the best example, but it helps to understand flexbox).

Answer (score 0):

I usually don't like W3Schools, but their education on flexbox was useful for me. It is actually very easy to understand.

Flex layouts use flex items that can take on many different alignment forms naturally without brute force.

Flex items can stack, align side-by-side, in mutiple direction, auto-calculate the spacing with and around those items and between them for even spacing and etc. They can replicate block (top to bottom) and inline (left to right), and even more. They are not bias to one-direction, but open to a number of variations of directions by nature.

[View Here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)